# Create an option with two arguments?

Tags: java, command-line-interface

Using Apache commons CLI. I'm trying to create an option that takes in two arguments. I want option "K" to be followed by a string argument (required) and a integer argument (not required).

I'm familiar using Option.builder like this
Option.builder("k").hasArg().optionalArg(true).required(false).desc("string").build();

but how do I build an option with two arguments inputted for option k?

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/apidocs/org/apache/commons/cli/Option.Builder.html

I looked into using the optionBuilder om the commons/cli website, but they don't give examples on how to build with two arguments.

Option KOption = Option.builder("k")
                .hasArg()
                .numberOfArgs(2)
                .optionalArg(true)
                .required(false)
                .desc("argument with required string and optional integer").build();

Comment: Don't know the API but [numberOfArgs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/apidocs/org/apache/commons/cli/Option.Builder.html#numberOfArgs(int)) would be the first thing I'd try.